# How to create alternative URL / Alias in Apache for Tomcat (only visible to the user)

Tags: jsf, tomcat, mod-rewrite, redirect, apache2

I'm using Apache2 -> mod_jk -> Tomcat7

I'm using the following URL to call a JSF web application: http://server/foo

Now, I also like to call it with the URL: http://server/bar

Calls to `foo` should always be changed to `bar`.

As Tomcat requires and relates to `/foo`, any JSF `request.getContextPath()` returns `/foo`. Subsequent page calls therefore are resulting in browser-urls containg `/foo` instead of `bar`.

> What do I need to change in order to keep tomcats foo-paths while the
>   user sees bar-paths in the browser?

Here is my config so far:

/etc/apache2/conf.d/test.conf

```
Alias /foo "/original/path"
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "/bar(.*)" "/foo$1" [PT]
<Directory "/original/path">
.... 
</Directory>
```

/.../tomcat7/conf/Catalina/localhost/test.xml

```
<Context path="/foo" ...></Context>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Needed an additional foo.xml in tomcat7/conf/Catalina/localhost
2. ...

   Alias /foo "/original/path"
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule "/bar(.*)" "/foo$1" [PT]

   ....